# Utilizando JPA com H2 Database

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Peço desculpas por ter postado minha dúvida no encadeamento de uma outra similar. Por isso estou postando como novo tópico, ok?

Estou utilizando o banco de dados H2 e JPA para criar minhas tabelas.

Testando minha aplicação, consigo criar as tabelas, inserir registros, listar os registros inseridos, porém não consigo visualizá-la na Console através do navegador utilizando o endereço localhost:8082, que me abre a janela para conexão com o Banco de Dados.

Segue abaixo o meu persistence.xml, o log4j.properties, a classe que gera as tabelas e a saída do log4j na Console:

### persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<persistence-unit name="h2_pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:C:/Users/Augusto/workspace/h2database/db/bd_test" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### Meu log4j:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%r [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=TRACE
```

### Minha classe para geração das tabelas:

```
package testes;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class GerarTabelas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("h2_pu");
            factory.close();
            System.out.println("Tabelas geradas com sucesso !!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao gerar as tabelas !!! Verificar as entidades !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

O resultado da consulta via código Java está correto, conforme abaixo:

```
1 - Andrea Lopes -- Obs 01 
2 - Beatriz Sampaio -- Nenhuma obs
3 - Carlos Carvalho -- Obs 03
4 - Daniel Carneiro -- Obs 04
5 - Edson Rabelo -- Obs 05
6 - Fernanda Monteiro -- Obs 06
7 - Guilherme Fontes -- Obs 07
8 - Helena Gomes -- Obs 08
9 - Ivan Reis -- Obs 09
10 - Janaina Ferreira -- Décima obs
```

No navegador, quando conecto à base de dados, tento acessar a tabela Cliente para verificações, consultas e etc. manualmente, utilizando o comando:

```
SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.BD_TEST.CLIENTE;
```

e obtendo erro conforme abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.BD_TEST.CLIENTE;
Table "BD_TEST" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.BD_TEST.CLIENTE [42102-180] 42S02/42102 (Help)
```

Qual a forma correta de executar esta query no H2?

Agradecendo antecipadamente qualquer ajuda,

atenciosamente

Augusto Cesar

Answer (score 2):

A [gramática do comando `SELECT`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#table_expression) do H2 não tem o banco de dados. Só pode ter o nome da tabela, prefixado ou não com o *schema*. Os exemplos do [*Quickstart*](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html) corroboram com isso.

Pense que a base já está definida na conexão, então não é como nos outros SGBDRs.

Portanto, tente executar:

```sql
SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.CLIENTE;
```

Ou:

```sql
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE;
```